# Parsing different structured xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

Currently I have tried using xml.dom.minidom.parser and xml.etree.ElementTree for this file that has different table structure.

Whenever I try to use those commands, I get an error message "ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 300606, column 37"

The file that I am working with is omia.xml.zip file from https://omia.org/download/.
What can I do to handle this kind of formatted file?

I was trying to use beautifulsoup with xml, and lxml, but seems like I have some problem there too. (I pip install lxml, but its not being recognized)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding problem with element content. Here's what xmllint reports:

```
$ unzip -p ~/Downloads/omia.xml.zip | xmllint --noout -
-:300606: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 2
        <field name="journal">Bulletin et Memoires de la Societe Centrale de Medic
                                           ^
-:300606: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 2
        <field name="journal">Bulletin et Memoires de la Societe Centrale de Medic
                                                              ^
-:300606: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 2
        <field name="journal">Bulletin et Memoires de la Societe Centrale de Medic
                                                                 ^
-:300606: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 2
        <field name="journal">Bulletin et Memoires de la Societe Centrale de Medic
                                                                                 ^
-:322053: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: row line 322042 and field
        <field name="doi"></field>
                                  ^
-:322054: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: table_data line 19 and row
    </row>
          ^
-:328921: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: database line 3 and table_data
    </table_data>
                 ^
-:1389753: parser error : xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node
        <field name="gene_id">388093963</field>
                                               ^
```

You may be able to filter the invalid characters, but I'm unsure how that would impact your expected results.